# A tripical problem in number theory

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Show that any integer greater than
$\dfrac{n^4}{16}$ can be written in at most one way as the product of two of its divisors
having difference not exceeding $n$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: A nice question but in future you should give more details of your own efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K$ be the integer and $K=AB=CD$ be its two factorizations where we can suppose that $A>C\ge D>B$.

Let the g.c.d. of $A$ and $C$ be $X$ and of $B$ and $D$ be $Y$. Then we can express these numbers as products of integers as follows:- $$A=aX,B=bY,C=bX,D=aY.$$

Now $A-B=aX-bY\le n$. Then $$a+Y\le a(X-Y)+(a-b)Y=aX-bY\le n $$ and so $aY\le\dfrac{n^2}{4}.$
$$b+X\le b(X-Y)+(a-b)X=aX-bY\le n$$ and so $bX\le\dfrac{n^2}{4}.$

We now have $K=abXY\le\dfrac{n^4}{16}.$